# CSS3 transitions when div content changes and div grows

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a div that get's filled with text. That text changes when different buttons get clicked and the div grows and shrinks to accommodate the text (as divs normally do when you use CSS). It has a background and a border and I wanted to use CSS3 transitions to have the div grow and shrink smoothly with a little animation. For some reason my code isn't working. I wrote:

```
div.div-in-question {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 50px;
    width: 600px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

It still just grows and shrinks like normal with no animation or smoothness.

I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skipallmighty/580w9c8h/) that I thought would work based on how I thought CSS3 transitions worked.

Comment: You can not transition an auto height – you would have to set a specific height for a transition to work.

Comment: Have a look at this answer and see if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938460/css-transition-auto-height-not-working/13938698#13938698

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this with jQuery

[JSIFFLDE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/580w9c8h/1/)

```
$("body").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("ul").append("<li>Another row</li>");
    $("ul li").slideDown();
});
```

**EDIT**

I've added easing "easeOutBounce" soo it looks like falling down from upper element

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/580w9c8h/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This Works

```
$(function(){
    $("body").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("<li>Another row</li>").appendTo("ul").hide().slideDown();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why, but I created a little sample animation deal here, and it doesnt work with that

```
 div.div-in-question{}
```

selector, just

```
.div-in-question{}
```

Try that.

http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/d06ynxy5/

Comment: Yes but that works because you are specifying a new height of the div. The div is not growing dynamically.

Comment: Playing with it. Here is fiddle to illustrate problem (sorry didnt see yours at first). http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/d06ynxy5/2/